# react-native app in visual studio code + eslint + prettier

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I have a problem with eslint and prettier in my react-native app when opened in visual studio code. See the picture. What am I doing wrong? [image]

Comment: import {React, Fragment} from react;     try this

Comment: You might visit: https://www.mythisdev.com/React-native-project-setup/ and goto "Eslint 與 Prettier settings" part and skip those Chinese words.

Answer (score 1):

You do nothing wrong. It's your ESlint that keeps your code clean, as follows:

`{Fragment}` → `{ Fragment }`

`'react'` → `"react"` and `'react-native'` → `"react-native"`

And `StatusBar` is the last element of the object so there shouldn't be a comma next to it.

Note: you should set up Prettier so that it can automatically correct your code in accordance to ESlint format rules.

Comment: Thanks for answer but my problem is like that https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/781